# JPA: Pessimistic locking of a row with select for update in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa, locking, openjpa

I got an oracle table with data like the following:

table:

```
create table myobjects(id int, objname varchar(20), state int);
```

data:

```
id / objname / state
1 / 'object no. 1' / 2
2 / 'object no. 2' / 1
3 / 'object no. 3' / 1
4 / 'object no. 4' / 1
5 / 'object no. 5' / 1
6 / 'object no. 6' / 1
7 / 'object no. 7' / 1
```

Now I have multiple batch instances which should

1. lock one object row of the table with state = 1 (the statement(s) should return maximum one object row, the first available/unlocked object row that can be found or no row, if none is available)
2. set the state of the object row to 2, commit,
3. do some work for that row, set state to 3 and commit.

To generate the statements, I use openjpa... but if necessary, oracle native statements would be possible, too.

For step 1., I tried this statement:

```
select * from myobjects where state = 1 and rownum <= 1 for update skip locked;
```

==> locks all objects with state 1, rownum <=1 is ignored

So the first batch instance would lock all objects --> bad

Another possibility, that I could think of (fallback), would be to select (for example) 10 rows with state 1 without locking and
then lock one row by its id:

```
select * from myobjects where state = 1 and rownum <= 10;
-- 'try and error' locking with all of them
select * from myobjects where id = :id for update;
```

==> really many sql calls needed... --> there must be a better solution

Could you help me to find a better solution?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: Please: solutions, without stored procedures, only.

Comment: What about: select * from myobjects where state = 1 and id in (select min(id) from myobjects where state = 1) for update

Comment: You are trying to re-implement a queueing system, so you may want to check the implementation of `Oracle AQ`, but the question is why don't you *use* it or some `JMS` implementation? There are lot of DIY queueings solution out there, but they typically don't scale and tend to "hang" time to time...

Comment: @aschoerk: with this solution, two batch instances try to lock the same object row. The second call always returns no result. Not what I need. What I need is, that every batch instance locks the next available object row.

Didn't mention this requirement above - I've added that.

Comment: @Marmite Bomber: "re-implement a queueing system".Yes, I am doing just that. Can you help me?

Comment: Is it possible to use thread/batch-specific state uuid. Then do 
"update myobjects set state = uuid where state = 1 and id in (select min(id) from myobjects where state = 1)" 
select id from myobjects where state = uuid 
You don't need to use pessimistic locking for that. The locking is done by using your specific identifier in the state

Comment: I like your answer in the comment, even if it is a non-pessimistic-locking solution. If you make an 'Answer' out of that, I will Accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Is PL/SQL allowed?  try:

```
declare
   id int;
begin
   update myobjects
   set state=2
   where state = 1
   and rownum = 1 
   returning id into id;

   commit;

   dbms_output.put_line(id);
end;
```

It works for me using 2 independent SQL Developer sessions.

Comment: Sorry, cannot use PL/SQL.

Comment: @markus, why not?  It doesn't make sense to use an Oracle database and not use the powerful features that come with it.

Comment: We try to be database-independent as far, as possible... Maybe another database will be put on the roadmap some day with a different low-level language. All that low-level code will have to be re-written, then.

I even wonder if 'for update *skip locked*' is a good idea...

Comment: 'for update' is added by jpa, but skip locked isn't.